# What categories and custom attributes do you use in you bug tracker?

Tags: bug-tracking

This one has been bugging me for a while now, but I never seem to be satisfied with the way the bug categories are defined in our bug tracker. It always seems like 90% of bugs go to "General" and 2/3 of the categories never get used.

How do you organize/categorize the bugs in your bugtracker?

Edit: I'm starting a new project on an ASP.NET MVC website. What would be your categories on an MVC website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use FogBugz's default fields, which are:

- Project (roughly mapped to a team)
- Area within project
- MileStone

You have to adapt these fields for your specific context. Have someone responsible for filling these fields correctly. The person in charge can be a project manager, a QA manager or a development team leader. They can periodically go over the bugs marked as "General" and create relevant categories, while removing dead categories.